# iOS Zbar SDK - Is there a way to capture an image at a user selected moment?

Tags: ios, zbar-sdk

Is there a way to take a photo with Zbar library?

I would like to give the user the possibility to take a picture while showing a started ZBarReaderView instance.

P.S.Don't need the image from which the Zbar library read the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

```
ZBarReaderViewController 

- (void) takePicture
Capture the next available frame and send it over the usual delegate path.
```